# Importar este método de extensión a mi clase C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estoy intentando usar este método de extensión que permite obtener el índice de fila mientras itero con foreach. Este método pertenece a [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). De su amplia librería de clases, me interesa este `SmartEnumerable`.

Tengo mi propia biblioteca de clases, llamada `MetodosExtension` en la cual dentro tengo varias cosas, entre ellas una carpeta llamada "Clases" y dentro de esta carpeta mi clase `Funciones.cs`. Quiero agregar el método de Jon a mi clase.

```
/// <summary>
/// Static class to make creation easier. If possible though, use the extension
/// method in SmartEnumerableExt.
/// </summary>
public static class SmartEnumerable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to make life easier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of enumerable</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source enumerable</param>
    /// <returns>A new SmartEnumerable of the appropriate type</returns>
    public static SmartEnumerable<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to make life easier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of enumerable</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source enumerable</param>
    /// <returns>A new SmartEnumerable of the appropriate type</returns>
    public static SmartEnumerable<T> AsSmartEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Type chaining an IEnumerable&lt;T&gt; to allow the iterating code
/// to detect the first and last entries simply.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to iterate over</typeparam>
public class SmartEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<SmartEnumerable<T>.Entry>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerable we proxy to
    /// </summary>
    readonly IEnumerable<T> enumerable;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enumerable">Collection to enumerate. Must not be null.</param>
    public SmartEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable==null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("enumerable");
        }
        this.enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumeration of Entry objects, each of which knows
    /// whether it is the first/last of the enumeration, as well as the
    /// current value.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerator<Entry> GetEnumerator()
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }
            bool isFirst = true;
            bool isLast = false;
            int index=0;
            while (!isLast)
            {
                T current = enumerator.Current;
                isLast = !enumerator.MoveNext();
                yield return new Entry(isFirst, isLast, current, index++);
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Non-generic form of GetEnumerator.
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents each entry returned within a collection,
    /// containing the value and whether it is the first and/or
    /// the last entry in the collection's. enumeration
    /// </summary>
    public class Entry
    {
        readonly bool isFirst;
        readonly bool isLast;
        readonly T value;
        readonly int index;

        internal Entry(bool isFirst, bool isLast, T value, int index)
        {
            this.isFirst = isFirst;
            this.isLast = isLast;
            this.value = value;
            this.index = index;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The value of the entry.
        /// </summary>
        public T Value { get { return value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether or not this entry is first in the collection's enumeration.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsFirst { get { return isFirst; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether or not this entry is last in the collection's enumeration.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsLast { get { return isLast; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// The 0-based index of this entry (i.e. how many entries have been returned before this one)
        /// </summary>
        public int Index { get { return index; } }
    }
}
```

Ya he recompilado mi Biblioteca, tengo agregado el DLL en el proyecto donde deseo invocar el método y también el `using` correspondiente.

Quiero usarlo así:

```
using System;
//.....
using MetodosExtension.Clases;

public class Prueba
{
   public void Prueba()
   {
        ///Asumiendo que mi "table" esta lleno....
        foreach (var item in table.Rows.AsSmartEnumerable())
        {
            int index = item.Index;
            DataRow value = item.Value;
            bool isFirst = item.IsFirst;
            bool isLast = item.IsLast;
        }
   }
}
```

Pero el compilador me muestra:

> "DataRowCollection" no contiene una definición para "AsSmartEnumerable" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión "AsSmartEnumerable" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "DataRowCollection" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Como ya mencioné tengo agregado el ensamblado y la directiva `using`.

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2017, .NetFrameWork 4.5.2

**Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

---

> - Pueden ver la [página de uso](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) para más detalles.
> - Si desea darle un vistazo a la Librería completa [MiscUtil](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/)

Comment: Debes agregar tu elemento como un objeto AsSmartEnumerable algo como: var listaRenglones=new SmartEnumerable<row>(table.Rows).

Comment: @MiguelZarate esto no funciona, y si se fija en el enlace de la página de uso, al final dice que puede usarse tal como quiero: `foreach (var entry in list.AsSmartEnumerable())`

Comment: O puedes usar DataRow last = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1]; y el primero solo es indice 0

Comment: @MiguelZarate el Punto es usar el método de extensión, no buscar una alternativa, porque bien puedo  usar un `For`, pero esta no es la idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de seguir investigando he dado con una solución para esto, básicamente esto debería funcionar con cualquiera [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8), lo que sucede en este caso es tal y como menciona Rafael Acosta en su respuesta, [`DataRowCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1) no implementa la interfaz `IEnumerable<T>` genérica.

[`DataTable.Rows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.7.1) solo implementa la interfaz **no genérica**. Lo que deriva de [`InternalDataCollectionBase`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase?view=netframework-4.7.1). Eso implementa la interfaz `ICollection` no genérica , lo que significa que el compilador no puede inferir el tipo de `row` más allá de solo `object`.

Así que para lograr este objetivo con un `DataTable.Rows` se debe usar LINQ para llamar a `Cast` y luego llamar a `AsSmartEnumerable` en el resultado, de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (var item in tabla.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsSmartEnumerable())
{
      int index = item.Index;
      DataRow value = item.Value;
      bool isFirst = item.IsFirst;
      bool isLast = item.IsLast;
}
```

Esto no es específico para `DataTable`: cada vez que tiene algo que solo se implementa en `IEnumerable` lugar de `IEnumerable<T>` (y no tiene un método `GetEnumerator` más específico para que lo use el compilador), el tipo de elemento de iteración inferido es justo `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Si te das cuenta, en la clase `SmartEnumerable`, tienes el **método de extensión** y genérico `AsSmartEnumerable<T>` el cual **extiende** a la interfaz **`this`** `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public static SmartEnumerable<T> AsSmartEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
}
```

Esto quiere decir que solo aquellas Clases que **implementen la interfaz** `IEnumerable<T>`, podrán utilizar el método de extensión `AsSmartEnumerable<T>`.

En tu caso, estás recurriendo en el Foreach la filas (Rows) de una tabla que son del tipo `DataRowCollection` (tal y como indica el error). Y lo que ocurre es que `DataRowCollection` **NO implementa la interfaz** `IEnumerable<T>`.

Para que te funcione el ejemplo, deberías utilizar una lista genérica **`List<T>`**, que **SI implementa la interfaz** `IEnumerable<T>`.

Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
        // Ejemplo para recorrer una Lista de Strings.
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in lista.AsSmartEnumerable<string>())
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Buena explicación, pero que sucede en este caso mire esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540839/8933039 Aquí si funciona para `DataRowCollection`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez: En ese ejemplo parece correcto, pero no da información de que tipo es el objeto `temptable` y no me creo que funcione ;). Mírate este ejemplo de cómo convertir un DataTable a una List<T>: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list)

Comment: Aunque no se menciona que tipo de Objeto es, se deduce que es un `DataTable`, por la forma de operar... Pero igual gracias por el enlace, esperaré un poco más, hasta ver si alguien más se anima a responder. De lo contrario marcaré su respuesta como aceptada. Como adicional la llamada aquí : `foreach (var item in lista.AsSmartEnumerable())` se puede simplificar no es obligatorio usar `<string>`